# May one make oatmeal on Shabbos?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, food

May one make oatmeal on Shabbos? 
It is easy to take care of the bishul problem by using a kli shlishi (according to [Igros Moshe OC vol. 4 74:15](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=920&st=&pgnum=139) and others who hold that there is never bishul in a kli shlishi), but does mixing the oatmeal with water constitute Losh (kneading)?

Comment: I was going to point out that R' Moshe on your behalf as well.

Answer (score 6):

In terms of Losh - [Rabbi Kagonoff](http://rabbikaganoff.com/archives/289) writes:

> WHAT IS LOSH?
>
> The concept of losh is to combine fine powders or similar small items
>   into a unit by adding liquid (Shevisas HaShabas). Thus, mixing clay
>   for pottery, or cement and sand into concrete, violate the Torah
>   prohibition of losh (see Rambam, Hilchos Shabbos 8:16; Rashi, Shabbos
>   74b). **Similarly, mixing oatmeal or reconstituting instant mashed
>   potatoes violates the Torah prohibition of losh (in addition to
>   whatever prohibitions of cooking may be involved).**

Comment: Would this not depend on how thin/thick the oatmeal is?

Comment: I don't know why that would be. Oatmeal isn't a powder.  In siman 321 there are many mutar cases similar to oatmeal. Kemach Kelli, Shesisa, Matza meal... Anyway, rabbi kagonoff is not really a source.